# Mock/not-mock response on a per request basis in Integration test

Tags: java, c#, mocking, integration-testing, wiremock

I am writing Integration tests. I have a need where for a positive test case request hit an actual service and recieve the response. But for a negative test case I must get the mocked response.

I am curious to understand if there is a way that I can mock/not-mock the request on a per configuration basis. Like for example if request accepts email address in request and I provide

1. "invalid@email.com" - response from mockoon must be a mocked response.
2. "valid@email.com" - mocking must not happen but rather it must hit the actual server to get the response. may be via redirecting or calling the actual service and responding the response to the caller.

I have tried Mockoon but feature is not yet present. So trying to help from the community :)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate stub/mappings that match on different emails.
Assuming that your url is `some-Url` and uses a queryParameter of email...

```json
{
    "request": {
        "url": "/some-Url",
        "queryParameters": {
            "email": {
                "equalTo": "invalid@email.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "request": {
        "url": "/some-Url",
        "queryParameters": {
            "email": {
                "equalTo": "valid@email.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "proxyBaseUrl": "http://my-other-url.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [mockswitch](https://mockswitch.com) - it supports various request / response pairs kinda like a switch case. You can define different cases and do request matching based on for each. If one the case matches it breaks the response flow and responds. Also easy to proxy requests to actual service based on certain case.

[image]

Their docs is available here https://mockswitch.com/docs/#switch-case-responses